# Accessing API in a function in a file in node.js and then deploying that file through firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am new to firebase. I am trying to create a Weather bot on Dialogflow. But, firebase doesn't seem to be able to access openweather API when index.js file is deployed. At the same time this works just fine in Command prompt. 
The following error occurs while executing
`https.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&APPID={APPID}",function(response){...})`
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
What's the problem here? How do I get around this?

```
function xyz(){  
//Code  
var https= require("https");  
var city=London;  
https.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&APPID={APPID}",function(response){  
//Code  
});  
//Code  
}
```

Comment: Can you plz show where are you using firebase?

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show how you use Firebase, so can't be throwing that error. Please update your question to include the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**Google Cloud Functions** doesn't allow to access *Outbound networking calls* to APIs other than that of Google Services in their free plan(*Spark*). If you want to make such call then you have to upgrade your plan. The fact that it is working on your local system is that local system allows making *Outbound network calls* to other services.
You can find more about pricing from here [Google Pricing Plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

A small advice from my side is to use **AWS Lambda** if you don't want to pay and use it as free service to make *Outbound networking calls*.